# WordPress : Genesis Framework add Class

Tags: wordpress, genesis

Are you able to add classes to the genesis themes structure?

For example:

```
do_action('genesis_before_header');
do_action('genesis_header');
do_action('genesis_after_header');
```

Where are these functions initialised and where can I add to them or create my own?

Answer (score 0):

Example `do_action( 'genesis_header' );`, if you wish to change the class of your header or HTML mark up for example, use this codes.

**THIS IS THE DEFAULT STRUCTURE**

```
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_open', 5 );
function genesis_header_markup_open() {
    genesis_markup( array(
        'html5'   => '<header %s>',
        'xhtml'   => '<div id="header">',
        'context' => 'site-header',
    ) );
    genesis_structural_wrap( 'header' );
}
function genesis_header_markup_close() {
    genesis_structural_wrap( 'header', 'close' );
    genesis_markup( array(
        'html5' => '</header>',
        'xhtml' => '</div>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_close', 15 );
```

**THIS IS YOUR CUSTOM STRUCTURE**

```
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_open', 5 );
remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_close', 15 );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_open_custom', 5 );
function genesis_header_markup_open_custom() {
    genesis_markup( array(
        'html5'   => '<div %s>',
        'xhtml'   => '<div id="my-header">',
        'context' => 'my-header',
    ) );
    genesis_structural_wrap( 'header' );
} 
function genesis_header_markup_close_custom() {
    genesis_structural_wrap( 'header', 'close' );
    genesis_markup( array(
        'html5' => '</div>',
        'xhtml' => '</div>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_header_markup_close_custom', 15 );
```

Or simply add a custom function that contains your custom HTML mark-up and classes. Use this

```
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'opening', 6 );
add_action( 'genesis_header', 'closing', 14 );
function opening(){
    echo '<div class="opening">'; //Opening div element 
}
function closing(){
    echo '</div>'; //Closing div element
}
```

**Output**

[image]

To know where is the genesis structure located, visit this folder

```
theme/genesis/genesis/lib/structure
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: can we modified the genesis folder .. usually is that correct ?

Comment: On my opinion, No its not correct .. that why genesis provide a child theme to override the parent genesis theme set up. You can modified genesis theme via child theme anyway .. the only problem is you are not familiar with this theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a body class on a particular template, try

```
//* Add custom body class to the head
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class' );
function my_body_class( $classes ) {
   $classes[] = 'YOUR-CLASS-HERE';
   return $classes;
}
```

For other code snippets and use cases, try https://my.studiopress.com/snippets/custom-body-class/.